# React why use useContext over creating many useState hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to create a taxi application and manage the state to reduce re-renders and prop drilling. I currently have 5 tables (Booking, Customer, Driver, Taxi, Review) and am thinking of creating context for each of them which would entail something like below:

```js
<Provider1>
   <Provider2>
      <Provider3>
         <ComponentToRender />
...
```

However, not every field in each context is required for each of the consumers - meaning unnecessary re-renders will occur. Instead of going through the trouble of implementing the `useMemo` hook, would it be more efficient to just have a bunch of `useState` variables?

For example, a `useState` variable for each of the `useContext` keys:

```
userContext: {
   firstName
   lastName
   phoneNumber
   ...(~12 rows)
}
```

This will reduce re-renders but if this is possible, then what's the point of state management using `useContext` aside from reducing prop drilling? I feel like it's more for accessing data than managing state data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's time to use a state management library. I'd recommend `recoil`

As you said, because of the way React works, prop drilling causes unnecessary and inevitable re-render.
Even if, you use `useMemo` that doesn't solve the problem completely. Because if the parent's state changed, it will re-render anyway.

`recoil` solve those problems. Check this link > https://recoiljs.org/

You can use your state any components that its in need. And when you update your state, only the components which subscribes the state will re-render.